# Is this good idea to store attributed string in a Structure in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

```
struct BookPage {
    var title: String
    var pageUrl: String
    var attributedText: NSAttributedString
}
```

I have model for Book Page which holds page information. Is it ok to store reference type - attributed string - as part of structure?

Comment: is there a reason that you think it may not be a good idea?

Comment: I was concerned abut how reference semantic will play role if model get accidentally shared and modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in practice it'ok to store attributed string like this.

Usually the concern about this would be the case where one for instance creates a mutable attributed string and then puts it in a structure like this. Then if that string is mutated in some other part of the program that may be unexpected for you that the string in your structure has also changed (it's the same object).

So you should be cautious about situations like the one described above.

Answer (score 1):

I don´t see why you could not store it in your model. An `NSAttributedString` is an object and it´s common to store objects in models, so go ahead.